# Android Studio Updating Access Denied

Tags: android, android-studio

> Temp. directory: C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Temp\
>   java.io.IOException: Cannot delete file C:\Program
>   Files\Android\Android
>   Studio\gradle\gradle-2.14.1\lib\native-platform-osx-i386-0.10.jar at
>   com.intellij.updater.Utils.delete(Utils.java:69) at
>   com.intellij.updater.DeleteAction.doApply(DeleteAction.java:47) at
>   com.intellij.updater.PatchAction.apply(PatchAction.java:188) at
>   com.intellij.updater.Patch$3.forEach(Patch.java:334) at
>   com.intellij.updater.Patch.forEach(Patch.java:386) at
>   com.intellij.updater.Patch.apply(Patch.java:329) at
>   com.intellij.updater.PatchFileCreator.apply(PatchFileCreator.java:84)
>   at
>   com.intellij.updater.PatchFileCreator.apply(PatchFileCreator.java:75)
>   at com.intellij.updater.Runner.doInstall(Runner.java:319) at
>   com.intellij.updater.Runner$1.execute(Runner.java:280) at
>   com.intellij.updater.StandaloneSwingUpdaterUI.lambda$doPerform$3(StandaloneSwingUpdaterUI.java:174)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I am trying to update my android studio to 2.3 but this error happened.
What should I do?

Comment: try to delete all contents of your gradle temp folder

Comment: and don't use gradle 2.14.xx but instead download and use the latest gradle version

Comment: Sorry for late reply. 
I tried to delete temp folder's item but still getting the same error..

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the contents of your `Gradle` temp folder.

> `File` => `Settings` => `Build, Execution, Deployment` => `Gradle` =>
>    and you should see temp folder path (Service directory path)

**Also** don't use `Gradle 2.14.xx` but instead download and use the latest `Gradle` version from [here](https://gradle.org/releases)